# SQL:how to perform select only on some characters from a column

Tags: sql, select

I wanted to know how to perform the SQL SELECT operation on only a particular range of characters.
For example,I've got an SQL query:

`SELECT date,score from feedback GROUP BY date`

Now this date is of format `yyyy/mm/dd`.

So I wanted to strip the days or cut out the days from it and make it `yyyy/mm`, thereby selecting only 0-7 characters from the date.

I've searched everywhere for the answer but could not find anything.Could I maybe do something like this?

`SELECT date(7),score from feedback GROUP BY date(7)`

Comment: what is your rdbms? why not convert your string to date? things would be much easier.

Comment: It is a date filed and not string

Comment: so what is your rdbms, there are function to truncate the day from a `DATE`  But that isnt the question, truncate will make  the date `YYYY/MM/01`, maybe you want the format function? again depend on your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSQL you use **[LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177601(v=sql.120).aspx)** other use **[substring](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)**

```
SELECT LEFT('abcdefg',2);
-- 
ab
```

So in your case

```
SELECT LEFT(date,7), score
FROM feedback
GROUP BY LEFT(date,7)
```

But again things will be much easier if you use a date field instead a text field.

Comment: it is a date field actually and not a text field

Comment: that is weird, LEFT is for strings, not dates/

Comment: Got no idea how it worked here too.But it gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your date field is an actual date field (or even a datetime field) the following solution would work:

```
select left(convert(date ,getdate()),7) as Year_Month
```

Changing `getdate()` to your `date` field, it would look like:

```
select left(convert(date , feedback.date),7) as Year_Month
```

Both queries return the following:

```
2016-01
```

Comment: so how would that query look like SELECT date,score form feedback GROUP BY date

Comment: It would look like this:  select left(convert(date , feedback.date),7) as Year_Month FROM feedback GROUP BY left(convert(date , feedback.date),7)